# Include one page PDF in existing .tex-file without letting design template influence apperance

Tags: templates, pdfpages

I'm having a huge *.tex-file which is based on the KOMA-class. I'm using a design-template from my university to modify the appearance. The design-template adds colored bars on top of each page and lines at the botttom.

This causes trouble when I want to add one single page using \includepdf. I want this page to be exactly as it is. Sadly even on this page I get colored bars behind the included pdf at the top of the page.

I also tried to generate my big pdf first and then merge it afterwards with the single page:

```
\includepdf[pages={1-2}]{Thesis}
\includepdf[pages=-]{SinglePage}
\includepdf[pages={3-last}]{Thesis}
```

Unfortunately this breaks the hyperrefs.

So I am interessted if there is any way to simply include one pdf-page in a document without the design-templates messing with it.

It seems I can't even add a completely empty page. Even using

```
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
```

still results in an empty page but with a colored bar at the top.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Without knowing anything about the template you are using, we cannot really help much

Comment: Well, it's from my university and I know it uses the KOMA-scrreprt-class. It contains out of some *.cls and *.sty files and some extra fonts. But I suspect this might not be really helpful.

Comment: No, a link would be helpful (though, I'm not at a computer right now). I can think of several ways those lines could be added. But then again, if that is what the university demands, what gives you the right to counter that demand

Comment: Addition: I know, a lot of these demands may be rubbish. But if they provided you with a genuine design, think hard before you change it.

Comment: The template can be downloaded at http://exp1.fkp.physik.tu-darmstadt.de/tuddesign/latex/latex-tuddesign/latex-tuddesign_1.0.20140928.zip Unfortunately the site is in german. Changing the template for one page is ok as my supervisor asked me to. The page to include already has the colored bars at a slightly different position.

Comment: I looked through the *.sty-files of the template and found the command \thispagestyle{realempty}. With `\newpage \thispagestyle{realempty} \mbox{}` I now get a completely empty page without any bars. Now I need to find a way to somehow but my one pdf-page instead.

Comment: use `pagecommand={\thispagestyle{realempty}}`  in the optional argument of `\includepdf`

Comment: Thank you very much everyone! I used `\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{realempty}}]{SinglePage}` and it works just fine. @UlrikeFischer if you post it as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Wanna wright up a short answer?

Answer (score 3):

Package `pdfpages` provides the option `pagecommand` which is useful in cases like yours.

```
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{realempty}}]{<pdfFileName>}
```